# Magento 2 no longer depends on DotdigitalGroup

Tags: composer, magento2.4.4, composer-update, class-not-found

After upgrading Magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.4, I am getting this error

```
[2022-09-19T12:09:48.690729+00:00] report.DEBUG: Source class "\Dotdigitalgroup\Sms\ViewModel\TelephoneInputConfig" for "Dotdigitalgroup\Sms\ViewModel\TelephoneInputConfig\Interceptor" generation does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Source class \"\\Dotdigitalgroup\\Sms\\ViewModel\\TelephoneInputConfig\" for


\"Dotdigitalgroup\\Sms\\ViewModel\\TelephoneInputConfig\\Interceptor\" generation does not exist. at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:223)"} []
```

After investigating, I found out that in a costomer code the class TelephoneInputConfig from    Dotdigitalgroup was used in project custom code but the modules from Dotdigitalgroup are no longer in composer.lock therefore vendor directory doesnt contain any package belongs to Dotdigitalgroup
Is there any alternative to this class I can use ?
thank you in advance

Comment: First, disable the module that uses the Dotdigitalgroup module.

Comment: I got 3 modules (in app/code")use Dotdigitalgroup\\Sms\\ViewModel\\TelephoneInputConfig, so my easy way is to require Dotdigitalgroup\\Sms\ in composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way was to require the messing module in composer.json

composer require dotdigital/dotdigital-magento2-extension-sms 1.4.1 --no-update

composer update

bin/magento setup:upgrade

after that everything works fine, there is  no conflict between dotdigital and Magento 2.4.4